# urban legend : why is it better to avoid using file descriptor 5?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

In the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283374/what-does-the-left-chevron-triangle-bracket-do), the answerer quoted a block of scripts, which contains a line like this

```
exec 4>/path/to/output.file
#and a third, for reading and writing, with FD 6 (it's not recommended to use FD 5)
```

I think he was refering to something not exclusively for this question. more like a general advice, but failed to provide the background. so, why should we try to avoid using file descriptor 5?

Comment: Maybe coming from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.bash.bug/E5Vdqv3tO1w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the footnotes at [tldp.org: I/O Redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#FTN.AEN17894)

> Using `file descriptor 5` might cause problems. When Bash creates a child process, as with exec, the child inherits fd 5 (see Chet Ramey's archived e-mail, SUBJECT: RE: File descriptor 5 is held open). Best leave this particular fd alone.

Comment: I wonder why a bug can exist through an extended amount of time (dating back to 1996) without getting fixed?

Comment: We call a bug like that a "feature". Its just the way it is and changing it might break things that rely on the behaviour.